# connectint to oracle data base through linux terminal error

Tags: linux, virtualbox, terminal

Trying to connect to oracle VM running Dev VM  in Linux terminal but I keep Getting this error message..... Any ideas on how to go through this ?? Thanks.

```
$ connect  DeveloperDaysVM2018-10-16_09.ova

ERROR: You must specify the destination port correctly.
      usage: connect [-dnhst45] [-p local-port][-R resolve] [-w timeout]
      [-H proxy-server[:port]] [-S [user@]socks-server[:port]]
      [-T proxy-server[:port]]
      [-c telnet-proxy-command]
      host port
```

Comment: `.ova` is not a valid port number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the host is

```
DeveloperDaysVM2018-10-16_09.ova
```

the port is missing. This is why you get the *usage* displayed. Just write the port after the host you want to connect to.

```
connect <host> <port>
```